How to simulate failed-then-succeeded cc refund ? Which credit card number to use?
We are implementing Stripe API.
How to simulate/replicate failed-then-succeeded Stripe refund using API
during testing in test mode?
I can't find credit card number to use for this scenario.
Stripe documentation has info on pending-then-succeeded scenario,
but not failed-then-succeeded.
How to simulate/replicate failed-then-succeeded Stripe refund using API, and which test credit card number to use?

They document most of their test cards here and they talk about how their refund failures work here. There is no such card to test exactly what you're looking for. I can imagine a use case where the refund fails which you can use the Asynchronous failure card. Then, you will still need to initiate a refund again to see the refund succeed so you can use the Asynchronous success card. It would not happen on the same card, however, everything else would act the same way.
